# Javascript button click listereners didn't redirect me to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm creating a shop cart and i started with a home page with 3 buttons
I had a little problem with redirecting those buttons to another pages
here's my html and javascript codes

I tried every possibility of redirection on javascript :(

```js
function inscription(){
var myForm = "inscription-form.html";
document.getElementById("btn1f").addEventListener('click' , function () {
    window.location.replace(myForm);
});
}
// redirect my second button
var myShop = "http://www.google.com";
document.getElementById("btn2s").addEventListener('click' , function () {
    window.location.replace(myShop);
});
// redirect my third button
function redirect(){
var myGoogle = "http://www.google.com";
document.getElementById("btn3g").addEventListener('click' , function () {
    window.location.replace(myGoogle);
});
}
```

```html
<section class="body-container">
        <div class="container-item title">
            <h1>Who said women need therapy &#128530;,
                <br> <br> We need shopping &#129297;
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container-item buttons">
            <div class="button-1">
                <span>Create an account?</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1f">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="button-2">
                <span>You're a customer &#128526;</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2s">Go Shopping</button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="button-3">
                <span>Not Interested</span>
                <button onclick="redirect()" type="button" class="btn" id="btn3g">Go Back</button>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: have you tried window.location.href = myShop

Comment: it seems you have created a function inscription() but did not initialize it in your DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>title</title>
     <script src="js.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
<section class="body-container">
        <div class="container-item title">
            <h1>Who said women need therapy &#128530;,
                <br> <br> We need shopping &#129297;
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container-item buttons">
            <div class="button-1">
                <span>Create an account?</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1f">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="button-2">
                <span>You're a customer &#128526;</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2s">Go Shopping</button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="button-3">
                <span>Not Interested</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn3g">Go Back</button>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </section>  
  </body>
</html>

//below into js.js file

window.onload = function() {
    var myShop = "http://www.google.com";
    document.getElementById("btn2s").addEventListener('click' , function () {
        window.location.href = myShop;
    });   
    
    var myGoogle = "http://www.google.com";
    document.getElementById("btn3g").addEventListener('click' , function () {
        window.location.href = myGoogle;

    });    
    var myForm = "inscription-form.html";
    document.getElementById("btn1f").addEventListener('click' , function () {
        window.location.href = myForm;
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have warpped the click listeners inside named functions and call those function onclick. So First time you click on a button the listeners is being attached and the second time, the listener will work (however second click also attachs another listener). So omit one of **onclick** or **addEventListener** one of them is enough. I prefer deleting named functions and **onclick** and just attach listeners (They should be attached at the end of document or after window load)

```js
window.onload=function(){

var myForm = "inscription-form.html";
document.getElementById("btn1f").addEventListener('click' , function () {
    window.location.replace(myForm);
});

var myShop = "http://www.google.com";
document.getElementById("btn2s").addEventListener('click' , function () {
    window.location.replace(myShop);
});

// redirect my third button
var myGoogle = "http://www.google.com";
document.getElementById("btn3g").addEventListener('click' , function () {
    window.location.replace(myGoogle);
});
}
```

```html
<section class="body-container">
        <div class="container-item title">
            <h1>Who said women need therapy &#128530;,
                <br> <br> We need shopping &#129297;
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container-item buttons">
            <div class="button-1">
                <span>Create an account?</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1f">Sign In</button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="button-2">
                <span>You're a customer &#128526;</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2s">Go Shopping</button>
            </div>
            
            <div class="button-3">
                <span>Not Interested</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn3g">Go Back</button>
            </div>
            
        </div>
</section>
```